# Quadrature Rule Error

Tags: integration

Question: Suppose that $S(f,h)$ is a quadrature rule for the integral $I= \int^b_a f(x) dx $ and that the error series is $c_4h^4+c_6h^6+...$ Combine $S(f,h)$ with $S(f,\frac{h}{3})$ to find a more accurate approximation of I.

So I got the easy part, that

$I-S(f,h)=c_4h^4+c_6h^6+...$

$I-S(f,\frac{h}{3})=c_4(\frac{h}{3})^4+c_6(\frac{h}{3})^6+...$

And now I need to combine them somehow. There is always adding the two together and solving for $I$, but I don't think that is what they want. As a side note if this was supposed to represent Simpson's Rule it would be much more obvious, but I don't think that $S(f,h)$ is referring to Simpson's but an arbitrary quadrature rule. If there were some way of making both right sides of the equations the same I would know where to go, but don't see how.

I don't want you to solve the problem for me, but if I could use some assistance on the next step to take (assuming this one is even right) that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to combine the two and cancel out the terms proportional to $h^4$.  Can you find a linear combination of $S(f,h)$ and $S(h,\frac h3)$ that does that?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but by combine do you mean just add what I have above in such a way that those proportional terms cancel? Like, am I one the right track as started above? To cancel out the $h^4$ terms I suppose you'd have to multiply the second S by $-3^{4n}$ or some such. Thanks for the help

Comment: That is exactly right.  You want to form a combination $I-aS(f,h)-bS(f,\frac h3)$ that doesn't have a fourth order error term.